# Go calling cmd script to kill self failed

Tags: go

I'm coding for a simple restartable Go application. I've searched for some information and started to implement it. Here is my plan:

1. Create a directory and store the `new version` of this application.
2. Prepare a `restart.cmd` file, which could be in the file system or embedded in the exe.
3. When upgrading, rename the current process's executable file and copy the new exec to the current path and disguise it as the current process's original name. Then call restart.cmd to close the current process and restart from the new application.

However, I encountered a problem. The script `restart.cmd` can't force kill the current running process and restart another one. It does create a cmd console and quickly close, which means the script is executed, but the current process is still running as if nothing happened unless I check the log file.

Here is my code:

---

Go Current Running Application:

```golang
package main

var (
    CurPath   string
    CurParent string
    CurName   string
    CurExt    string

    RenamePath = func(curName string) string {
        return filepath.Join(CurParent, "back", curName)
    }
    NewVersionPath = func(curName string) string {
        return filepath.Join(CurParent, "temp", curName)
    }

    CmdPath = func() string {
        return filepath.Join(CurParent, "scripts", "restart.cmd")
    }
    LogPath = func() string {
        return filepath.Join(CurParent, "log.log")
    }

    Log *log.Logger
)

func main() {
    initVar()
    renameCur()
    copyNew()
    restart()
}

func initVar() {
    executable, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    CurPath = executable
    CurParent = filepath.Dir(CurPath)
    CurName = filepath.Base(CurPath)
    CurExt = filepath.Ext(CurName)

    lf, err := os.OpenFile(LogPath(), os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0555)
    if err != nil {
        panic(lf)
    }
    Log = log.New(lf, "", os.O_APPEND)
}

func renameCur() {
    if err := os.Rename(CurPath, RenamePath(CurName)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    Log.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"), "Rename Current Running Process Executable File")
}

func copyNew() {
    cf, err := os.Create(CurPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cf.Close()
    nf, err := os.Open(NewVersionPath(CurName))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer nf.Close()
    if _, err = io.Copy(cf, nf); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    Log.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"), "Copy New Version Executable And Replace Current Path")
}

func restart() {
    err := exec.Command(CmdPath(), strconv.Itoa(os.Getpid()), CurPath).Start()
    if err != nil {
        Log.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"), "Restart Application Failure:", err)
    }
    // ================================
    //  Here Sleep Mock Running Server
    // ================================
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Hour)
}
```

---

Go New Application:

```golang
func main() {
    initVar()
    Log.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"), "Application v2.0 is Start to Run")
}
```

---

Restart.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pid=%1"
set "path=%2"
set "len=2"

set "v_args="
set "count=0"
for %%a in (%*) do (
    if !count! geq %len% (
        set v_args=!v_args! %%a
    )
    set /A count+=1
)

set "v_args=%v_args:~1%"

taskkill /F /PID %pid%
start "" %path%
```

---

As mentioned before, the new application starts successfully and prints the log, but the current application does not stop, which is unacceptable for an http server. Can anyone give me some advice on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm with @markus-w-mahlberg on this: unless you have really _weird_ requirements, it'd be much better to provide a proper Windows installation package which would restart your applciation–say, an MSI package using [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/), or (a much easier to use) InnoSetup which also [can manage restarts](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_restartapplications).

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work due to how processes are managed in modern operating systems.

Simplified: A shell instance calls your application and your application instance the kill script. However the nanosecond your application is killed all processes it spawned are killed, too. And your application instance is killed as soon as the shell calling it is killed.

That being said, processes can detach from the parent by what is called forking. Due to how go works, dealing with that can be tricky. While [func (*Cmd) Start](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Start) should do what you want (namely detaching the call to your script), it may cause the allocated resources of the kill script not being released (effectively making the script a [zombie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) on exit.

### A note from an old sysadmin

It is VERY bad practice for an application to effectively kill itself for updates. Updates are a sysadmin's concern, a well running application the developer's concern. Even in these days of devops, those are distinct areas of concern and should not be intertwined.